# PHP - Specifying server for exec'd command to be run on

Tags: php, ip-address, exec

Using PHP, `exec('php test.php');` will execute a separate PHP script on the command line.

What if `test.php` lives on another server, but within the same network?  Can I specify that server's local IP address for the shell command to be run?  What about a remote IP address?  I could always install Apache on the second server and call the remote script via http, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks, Brian

Comment: Can my computer tell your computer to run a program? Like one which sends me your bank passwords stored in your browser? No, no it can't, and neither can your PHP script tell another server to run a PHP script. You need a server running on the other computer waiting for commands, whether it's a web server (access its URL) or otherwise.

Comment: exec executes a shell command. It doesn't have magic powers to tell other systems to do anything - your shell program will have to take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Use `exec()` to execute a program that connects to this other server and does whatever.
2. Set up a web service on the receiving server, and have the sending server send a request.

Regardless of what you choose to do, you'll need some setup on the receiving end, for the obvious reasons Dan Grossman pointed out.